# Convert array from unsigned char* to char*

Tags: c++, char

Need to safe convert array from unsigned char* to char*.
I do it this way. Is it correct or not?

```
std::vector < unsigned char > arr;
char *imgData = (char*) malloc( arr.size() );
for ( int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++ ) imgData[ i ] = ( arr.at( i ) - 128 );
```

Comment: What do you mean by "safe convert"?

Answer (score 5):

No, that is not safe. Or more to the point, it's not well-defined behavior in C++.

`char` is allowed to be signed or unsigned, however the implementation sees fit. If `char` is unsigned, subtracting 128 from the `unsigned char` will just truncate half of the bits. And if `char` is signed, there's no guarantee that it's two's complement signed, so subtracting 128 won't do what you want.

The kind of conversion you're trying to do is not reasonable. You named the variable `imgData`, so it seems like you intend to send that data to some image API. And that API takes regular `char`. So your goal seems to be to convert each `unsigned char` into a `char` that shares the exact same bit-pattern of the original `unsigned char`.

In that case... just cast the pointer: `static_cast<char*>(arr.data())`. You're going to provoke undefined behavior either way; I'd rather do it in the way that's likely to actually work ;)

Also, it should be noted that C++14 makes it effectively impossible to implement a signed version of `char` that doesn't use two's complement. That's because of the need to support UTF-8 through a possibly-signed-`char` type. You have to be able to cast a `char*` into an `unsigned char*` and back, in such a way that the bit-pattern of all valid UTF-8 code units is preserved.

So the cast still is the option most likely to actually do what you want.

Comment: Why does converting `unsigned char*` to `char*` provoke a UB?

Comment: @ixSci: It's not the conversion; it's the accessing. Presumably, whomever is receiving `imgData` will actually read from it or write to it as a `char*`. If they do, then it's UB. If they cast it back to an `unsigned char*` before reading, then it would be well-defined.

Comment: One more question though, while I understand how wrting via `char*` to `unsigned char*` data might mess everything up I don't get why you are  saying that reading from this converted pointer is also UB. Won't it read well defined chars which were converted from the corresponding uchars?

Comment: @ixSci: What "corresponding uchars"? `char` can be signed, and there are many unsigned values that have no corresponding signed one. Remember: C++ doesn't define overflow semantics and the like. If you had 255 in an `unsigned char`, what does it look like as `char`? Who knows; C++ isn't going to say.

Comment: But [conv.integral] has rules for both conversions "s -> u" and back. Yes they are not exactly specified but implementation defined instead. Still it doesn't mean they are undefined does it? Given we have one program, compiled with one compiler which writes, converts and reads values — we can't have an undefined behavior. We can't say what the exact values there will be, that's true. But we are guaranteed they will be consistent(given the implementation is sane and not trying to sabotage us)